# Bash store JSON output to CSV

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

I have a bash script in which I am trying to store the aws command output (which is a JSON) to CSV file.
This is the JSON output of the aws s3 command.

```
{
  "Expiration": {
    "Days": 7
  },
  "ID": "Expire after 7 days",
  "Filter": {
    "Prefix": ""
  },
  "Status": "Enabled"
}
{
  "Expiration": {
    "Days": 1
  },
  "ID": "Remove after 1 day",
  "Filter": {},
  "Status": "Enabled"
}
```

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
y="Rule"
x=$(aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket test | jq -r '.Rules[]')
echo  ${y}, ${x} >> sample.csv
```

The JSON response is getting saved to sample.csv but in separate columns. I want it to be in 1 column and in pretty JSON format.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Where is the `Rules` property in the JSON?

Comment: @Barmar using the aws s3 command I got the above JSON response from "Rules" field

Comment: The JSON has nested objects, but CSV is flat. What do you expect the CSV to be like?

Comment: @Barmar I just want the full JSON to come in 1 column. If you see in the image its coming in multiple columns.

Comment: You need to quote the result, otherwise the `,` in the JSON will be field delimiters.

Comment: So you need to put double quotes around the JSON, and escape all the nested double quotes.

Comment: Do you need Bash? A language w/ support for JSON & CSV would be vastly easier. PHP, Python, JS, etc, etc...

Comment: @quickshiftin currently it has to be done in bash. If it gets more complicated will move to Python

Comment: by the time you try to parse json and write a csv, it will already be complicated enough for python imo.

Comment: Please add ouput of your `aws` command to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Oh, as the JSON isn't valid I thought that you wanted to generate a CSV with a rule per line, that is not the case?

Comment: @esahmo, it looks like you've been around here long enough, and asked enough questions, to know [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- show what your desired output is.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

I may have misunderstood what OP wanted. If it's a CSV with only one record then you can do:

```sh
y=Rule
x=$(aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket test | jq '.Rules[]')
jq -nr --arg y "$y" --arg x "$x" '[$y, $x] | @csv' > sample.csv
```

Please take notice that the JSON stored in the second column of the CSV is not strictly valid as it's composed of a stack of objects instead of an array.

---

##### Prior answer

You can use `jq`:

```sh
aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket test |
jq -r '.Rules[] | [ (. | tostring) ] | @csv'
```

CSV output:

```
"{""Expiration"":{""Days"":7},""ID"":""Expire after 7 days"",""Filter"":{""Prefix"":""""},""Status"":""Enabled""}"
"{""Expiration"":{""Days"":1},""ID"":""Remove after 1 day"",""Filter"":{},""Status"":""Enabled""}"
```

But as @ZachYoung pointed out, as of now `jq` doesn't have any easy way to generate pretty strings with `tostring` or `tojson`.

Personally I would stick to the compact version, but if the pretty formatting is really necessary then I would switch to `ruby` instead of `jq` (python is also an option but it lacks the one-liner thingy^^):

```sh
aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket test |
ruby -rjson -rcsv -e 'puts "Rules", JSON.parse(ARGF.read)["Rules"].map{|rule| [JSON.pretty_generate(rule)].to_csv}'
```

CSV output:

```
Rules
"{
  ""Expiration"": {
    ""Days"": 7
  },
  ""ID"": ""Expire after 7 days"",
  ""Filter"": {
    ""Prefix"": """"
  },
  ""Status"": ""Enabled""
}"
"{
  ""Expiration"": {
    ""Days"": 1
  },
  ""ID"": ""Remove after 1 day"",
  ""Filter"": {
  },
  ""Status"": ""Enabled""
}"
```

Comment: Good try, but OP said they wanted the JSON "pretty printed". (+1 still!)

Comment: @Fravadona are you suggesting to change the aws command to this ?
 

`bRules=$(aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket test | jq -r '.Rules[]' | tostring | @csv)`

Comment: @ZachYoung Thanks, I overlooked the "pretty printed"

Comment: @esahmo, that would be the simplest IMO: `bRules=$(aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket test | jq -r '.Rules[] | [ (. | tostring) ] | @csv')` but it all depends on how you'll use the `bRules` variable

Comment: On the money! Wish I could upvote again for getting the first output in a variable and using that again in another jq template: that was exactly the trickery I called out not knowing :)